# Keyboard shortcut for getting into the content pane on a Windows Explorer

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

I need to know if there is a keyboard shortcut for getting into the content pane on a Windows Explorer.

I already know the keyboard shortcut for getting into the address bar (<kbd>Alt + D</kbd>). Also, I know that I can navigate through different panes with the <kbd>F6</kbd> key. But this way is not very practical.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific key to go to the content pane directly.

But you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate between the Address bar, Search bar, Tool bar, Navigation pane, Content pane. For more windows explorer keyboard shortcuts refer this [page](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_7.html#link_5).

I have an extra option too. [AutoHotkey!](http://ahkscript.org/) Now-a-days, you can create your own keyboard shortcut as you desire. I don't know much about that. If you can, try to create one and post it here. :D